# Swagger's page shows as my web page's start page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, swagger

I am using Swagger as my API docs system. I have installed all necessary tools and it is working properly. However the problem I experience is that my start page shows Swagger's page. Any suggestions how can I resolve this issue?

Here is my Startup.cs - config file

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean the startup page when you actually start the project from Visual Studio? Or you mean that going to / path shows you swagger?

Comment: Can you post your launch.json?

Comment: I mean, if I run project, it show me swagger, instead of my /home/index @Andrew

Comment: use `launchSettings.json` to mention your `launchUrl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove prefix. Here's how I do it in my project:

```
    // ConfigureServices
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("path", new Info() { Title = "My API V1", Version = "v1" });
        });

    // Configure
    app.UseAuthentication():
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/path/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    });
```

Comment: @Eugene do you have launchSettings.json in the Properties folder?

Comment: @Eugene launchSettings.json is good. Have you tried removing prefix?

Comment: Yes. I get 404 not found, but it still try to use swagger. Also I see that I have now name of project (Too See Web(Swagger))

Comment: @Eugene Updated my answer with code from my project. `path` in SwaggerUI and SwaggerGen should be the same.

Comment: Yeah. Seems it helps

Answer (score 0):

The startup page is not something you configure in code. It's something you configure in the project properties from visual studio, since it only affects your development process.

You can find it by right clicking on the project, opening project properties and going to startup options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178730.aspx#Anchor_1